# Stop an Azure Function if parameters are missing (therefore not everytime)

Tags: node.js, http, azure-functions

I have the following code, which should be more or less self-explanatory, but I'll elaborate.

I want to stop the function and response with a status 400 and a message IF one or both parameters (which are required) are missing.

It appears as if it just ignores my `context.res = {}` from within the if-statement

```
const courseId = decodeURIComponent(
    req.query?.CourseId ||
    req.body?.CourseId,
)
const userId = decodeURIComponent(
    req.query?.UserId ||
    req.body?.UserId
)

// handling error if required params are missing
if (!userId || !courseId) {
    context.res = {
        status: 400,
        body: {
            errorMessage: 'Missing one or more of the required parameters: CourseId and/or UserId',
        },
    }
    context.done()
}
```

Comment: Hi, any update?

Comment: I haven't had the time to dig into it yet - will post the answer when I have the time :)

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    const userId = (req.query.userId || (req.body && req.body.userId));
    const courseId = (req.query.courseId || (req.body && req.body.courseId));
    context.log(userId);
    context.log(courseId);
    if (!userId || !courseId) {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: {
                errorMessage: 'Missing one or more of the required parameters: CourseId and/or UserId',
            },
        };
    }else{
        
        context.res = {
            // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
            body: "This is a test."
        };
    }
}
```